# Drupal 9 : How to disable cache for a specific page

Tags: php, symfony, caching, drupal

How I can disable the cache of a specific page in Drupal 9,
I found a solution, but it used to disable cache for all pages, the solution is: Add this code in settings.yml:

```
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, TRUE);
\Drupal\Component\Assertion\Handle::register();
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

That's work, but I want just to disable cache for a specific page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the *my_company.routing.yml* config file for your page, you can add the following *options.no_cache* attribute :

```
my_company.customer_detail:
  path: '/customer/{customer_entity}/detail'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_company\Controller\CustomerController::detailAction'
    _title: 'Fiche client'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    type: ^\d+
  options:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'
```

Comment: It will work only in case if custom controller exists. If that is a simple page for viewing content type, there should be another approach, like disabling cache in preprocess hook, or using specific tags to make cache updates when it's needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/9.0x) in order to disable cache. Something like:

```
function test_module_preprocess_node__landing_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
}
```

Where is **test_module** is your module name, **node** is your entity type and **landing_page** is your content type name.
This hook should be placed in your module *.module* file.

Also, I recommend you to take a look at the [Cache API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api) article, where you can find how to control caching of your site and how to use cache contexts and tags

Comment: If only ['max-age'] = 0 worked every time!!  Alas it does not. See  https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-max-age
"Unfortunately, max-age does not work for anonymous users and the Drupal core Page Cache module. "